# In Discord, can we allow only some people to tag @everyone?

Tags: permissions, discord

I know we can totally disable @everyone @all tags for everyone in both individual channels & also the whole server.

However, is it possible to allow only some people to tag @everyone but disallow others from tagging @everyone?

Is there a direct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, under "Server Settings" you can create a new role without the "Mention @everyone, @here, and All Roles" Permission:

[image: Allows members to use @everyone (everyone in the server) or @here (only online members in that channel). They can also @mention all roles, even if the role's "Allow anyone to mention this role" permission is disabled.]

Make sure that they don't get the permission from another role, such as @everyone, which gives it by default.